# How to build and HTML table using the values from code behind (C#)

Tags: html, html-table, code-behind

I am trying to build and html table using the string values from my code behind, which are obtained from the asp textbox. I tried doing

```
<td><%textbox1.text %></td>
```

but it did not work. Any ideas on how I can proceed?

Comment: I think you are just missing an `=` in front of textbox1

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<td><%textbox1.text %></td>
```

to this:

```
<td><%=textbox1.Text %></td>
```

Remember that C# is case sensitive also, you need the `=` sign after `%`

Answer (score 0):

You even don't need TextBox-ex.

Just add some property to your code behind:

```
public string MyString { get; set; }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    MyString = "<div>Some value.</div>";
    MyString = "Or this one value.";
}
```

and then use it in aspx:

```
<%=MyString %>
```